# Python3 Unit Test HTML Reporting

Tags: html, python-3.x, report, nose

Is anyone aware of any way to generate an HTML report via either nose or pyunit that is compatible with Python3? Everything I've found so far is for Python2 and breaks in Python3. I've tried fixing some of them but my Python skills just aren't there yet. Especially when it comes to difference between 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allure Framework has a branch with python 3 support

- Allure Report site - https://allurereport.org/
- Branch, you can build it and use - https://github.com/rusg77/allure-python/tree/python3
- Issue in allure python - https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python/issues/29

Hope it helps